# How do I type-assert that a value is a pointer (to a string)?

Tags: go

I'm trying to create a method that will return the length of a generic type.  If we have a string, we call len(string), or if its an array of interface{} type, we call len() on that as well.  This works well, however, it doesnt work in you pass in a pointer to a string (I'm assuming I'd have the same problem with arrays and slices as well).  So how can I check if I have a pointer, and dereference it?

```
func (s *Set) Len(i interface{}) int {
    if str, ok := i.(string); ok {
        return len(str)
    }
    if array, ok := i.([]interface{}); ok {
        return len(array)
    }
    if m, ok := i.(map[interface{}]interface{}); ok {
        return len(m)
    }
    return 0
}
```

Comment: I'd say, in a method `func (s *Set) Len(...) int` the last statement should be `panic("Can't get length of the value")` because of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22865084/720999).

Comment: Also note that your code has nothing to do with reflection--type assertions and type switches are "native" to Go programs while access to reflection is provided via the standard package aptly named `reflection`.

Comment: @kostix originally, I was trying to find a way to generically, check if the input was a pointer, and dereference it.  But I realized that was overcomplicated for what I need

Comment: Don't see why it was downvoted. One might have this question asked very legitimately in the code generation setting.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do the same thing as for the other types:

```
if str, ok := i.(*string); ok {
    return len(*str)
}
```

At this point you may want to use a [type switch](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Switch_statements) instead of the more verbose ifs:

```
switch x := i.(type) {
case string:
    return len(x)
case *string:
    return len(*x)
…
}
```

Comment: Nice, thanks for that.  I think the switch is definitely going to be more elegant